# android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.insp.placesapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: Please add a plain Englisch Question

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you're getting this error is because you're compiling whole

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

as it is, which causes `64K method limit` frequently.

I highly suggest not to compile like this, See [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), There is list of Google Play services API with Description in `build.gradle`.

See the list, and choose one that you really need and compile only those.